# Emgu CV SVM example not working on version 3.0.0

Tags: c#, svm, emgucv

I am trying to implement the SVM example code found 
[Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SVM_%28Support_Vector_Machine%29_in_CSharp). It is the official example provided at the Emgu CV documentation, but it is for version 1.5 (at least). 
Unless I have been very mistaken, a lot of the classes in this example either work differently in version 3.0.0 or don't exist at all and have been substituted.
One example is the `SVMParams` class which as shown [Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/b1771ec1-9e4b-1cd4-f6fb-ad89643dd50b.htm) doesn't exist anymore.
Also, the `TrainData` class has been developed which is the new input of the `TrainAuto` method of an SVM object, having substituted the `Matrix<single>` class.
I have tried to implement the example after changing what I believe needed change but the code reaches the `bool trained = model.TrainAuto(td, 5);` line and returns a Divide by zero exception.

Maybe there are more issues after this line but this is as far as my code compiles.
Here is what I am trying to execute:

```
private void Classify()
    {
        int trainingSampleCount = 150;
        int sigma = 60;

        #region Generate the training data and classes

        Matrix<float> trainData = new Matrix<float>(trainingSampleCount, 2);
        Matrix<float> trainClasses = new Matrix<float>(trainingSampleCount, 1);

        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(500, 500);

        Matrix<float> sample = new Matrix<float>(1, 2);

        Matrix<float> trainData1 = trainData.GetRows(0, trainingSampleCount / 3, 1);
        trainData1.GetCols(0, 1).SetRandNormal(new MCvScalar(100), new MCvScalar(sigma));
        trainData1.GetCols(1, 2).SetRandNormal(new MCvScalar(300), new MCvScalar(sigma));


        Matrix<float> trainData2 = trainData.GetRows(trainingSampleCount / 3, 2 * trainingSampleCount / 3, 1);
        trainData2.SetRandNormal(new MCvScalar(400), new MCvScalar(sigma));

        Matrix<float> trainData3 = trainData.GetRows(2 * trainingSampleCount / 3, trainingSampleCount, 1);
        trainData3.GetCols(0, 1).SetRandNormal(new MCvScalar(300), new MCvScalar(sigma));
        trainData3.GetCols(1, 2).SetRandNormal(new MCvScalar(100), new MCvScalar(sigma));

        Matrix<float> trainClasses1 = trainClasses.GetRows(0, trainingSampleCount / 3, 1);
        trainClasses1.SetValue(1);
        Matrix<float> trainClasses2 = trainClasses.GetRows(trainingSampleCount / 3, 2 * trainingSampleCount / 3, 1);
        trainClasses2.SetValue(2);
        Matrix<float> trainClasses3 = trainClasses.GetRows(2 * trainingSampleCount / 3, trainingSampleCount, 1);
        trainClasses3.SetValue(3);

        #endregion

        using (SVM model = new SVM())
        {
            //changed from example
            model.SetKernel(Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.SvmKernelType.Linear);
            model.Type = SVM.SvmType.CSvc;
            model.C = 1;
            model.TermCriteria = new MCvTermCriteria(100, 0.00001);

            TrainData td = new TrainData(trainData, Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.DataLayoutType.RowSample, trainClasses);
            bool trained = model.TrainAuto(td, 5);
            //changes up to this point

            for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
                {
                    sample.Data[0, 0] = j;
                    sample.Data[0, 1] = i;

                    float response = model.Predict(sample);

                    img[i, j] =
                        response == 1 ? new Bgr(90, 0, 0) :
                        response == 2 ? new Bgr(0, 90, 0) :
                        new Bgr(0, 0, 90);
                }
            }
            // changed the GetSupportVectors()
            Mat supvec = model.GetSupportVectors();
            int c = supvec.Height;

            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                // The way the data is received changed as well 
                byte[] b = supvec.GetData(i);
                float[] v = new float[] { (float)b[0], (float)b[1] };

                PointF p1 = new PointF(v[0], v[1]);
                img.Draw(new CircleF(p1, 4), new Bgr(128, 128, 128), 2);
            }
        }

        //display the original training samples
        for (int i = 0; i < (trainingSampleCount / 3); i++)
        {
            PointF p1 = new PointF(trainData1[i, 0], trainData1[i, 1]);
            img.Draw(new CircleF(p1, 2.0f), new Bgr(255, 100, 100), -1);
            PointF p2 = new PointF(trainData2[i, 0], trainData2[i, 1]);
            img.Draw(new CircleF(p2, 2.0f), new Bgr(100, 255, 100), -1);
            PointF p3 = new PointF(trainData3[i, 0], trainData3[i, 1]);
            img.Draw(new CircleF(p3, 2.0f), new Bgr(100, 100, 255), -1);
        }

        Emgu.CV.UI.ImageViewer.Show(img);
    }
```

Here is part of the stacktrace that describes the exception

```
at Emgu.CV.ML.MlInvoke.CvSVMTrainAuto(IntPtr model, IntPtr trainData, Int32 kFold, MCvParamGrid& cGrid, MCvParamGrid& gammaGrid, MCvParamGrid& pGrid, MCvParamGrid& nuGrid, MCvParamGrid& coefGrid, MCvParamGrid& degreeGrid, Boolean balanced)
at Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.TrainAuto(TrainData trainData, Int32 kFold, MCvParamGrid cGrid, MCvParamGrid gammaGrid, MCvParamGrid pGrid, MCvParamGrid nuGrid, MCvParamGrid coefGrid, MCvParamGrid degreeGrid, Boolean balanced)
at Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.TrainAuto(TrainData trainData, Int32 kFold)
```

I have no idea why the exception occurs as the data that is used for the method are created as per the example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems to solve:

1. `System.DivideByZeroException` is thrown (as @user3082029 explained) by using incorrect type for `trainClasses`, `trainClasses1`, `trainClasses2` and  `trainClasses3`. The type should be`Matrix<int>` instead of `Matrix<float>`
2. Since introduction of [optimize_linear_svm()](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/4997f5dfe9d1fa44f9576649a9f604026714ac1a/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp#L1544) function in OpenCV `Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.SvmKernelType.Linear` wouldn't produce expected support vectors known from [example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SVM_%28Support_Vector_Machine%29_in_CSharp). In this situation you can modify [opencv_ml](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/4997f5dfe9d1fa44f9576649a9f604026714ac1a/modules/ml) module and replace `opencv_ml300.dll` in your project. Or you can use `Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.SvmKernelType.Inter`
3. To draw support vectors you can use

   ```
   var supportVectors = model.GetSupportVectors();
   var vectors = new Matrix<float>(supportVectors.Rows, supportVectors.Cols, supportVectors.DataPointer);

   for (var i = 0; i < supportVectors.Rows; i++)
   {
       var p1 = new PointF(vectors[i, 0], vectors[i, 1]);
       img.Draw(new CircleF(p1, 4), new Bgr(128, 128, 128), 2);
   }
   ```

Comment: Assigning `supportVectors` as `var` instead of `Mat` worked. +1 for the SvmKernelType.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem like you, but it seems that `trainClasses` is now a matrix of integer and not a matrix of float anymore.
I try this and it worked form me in Vb.net:

```
Dim trainClasses As Matrix(Of Single) =>  Dim trainClasses As Matrix(Of Integer)
```

Tt would be in C#:

```
Matrix<float> trainClasses => Matrix<Int> trainClasses
```

Hope it works for you.
Guillaume

Comment: Thanks for answering. Getting `trainClasses` from float to integer got the model to be trained and working (not the way you implement it, but changing the definition from `Matrix<float>` to `Matrix<int>` at each `trainClasses` definition). I still cant get the support vectors correctly though.`getSupportVectors()` returns a `byte[]` and it needs to be a float, but no matter how I convert it, the values are either negative or close to zero. Shouldn't they be the pixel positions of some of the train examples?

Answer (score 0):

To draw support vectors Accurately, you must use a POLY type of kernel

```
model.SetKernel(SVM.SvmKernelType.Poly);
model.Degree = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The situation is the same with Emgu.CV 4.5.1 too. (which was used by me.)

```cs
bool _successful = _svm.TrainAuto(_traindatastructure, crossValidationParam);
```

returns the error,

```
************* Exception Text **************
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Emgu.CV.ML.MlInvoke.cveSVMTrainAuto(IntPtr model, IntPtr trainData, Int32 kFold, MCvParamGrid& cGrid, MCvParamGrid& gammaGrid, MCvParamGrid& pGrid, MCvParamGrid& nuGrid, MCvParamGrid& coefGrid, MCvParamGrid& degreeGrid, Boolean balanced)
   at Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.TrainAuto(TrainData trainData, Int32 kFold)
```

when there are type mismatches in the parameters of,

```cs
TrainData _traindatastructure = new TrainData(_samples, Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.DataLayoutType.RowSample, _responese);
```

**To solve the error simply convert the types of the input parameters as specified in the Emgu CV documentation** [here](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/eb8aa0b3-bba4-c343-e25b-d697893c264d.htm). Type conversion is done as follows.

```cs
Mat _samples = new Mat();
_traindata.ConvertTo(_samples, DepthType.Cv32F); // Matrix of samples. It should have CV_32F type.

Mat _responese = new Mat();
_trainclasses.ConvertTo(_responese, DepthType.Cv32S); // The matrix should have type CV_32F or CV_32S (in the former case the responses are considered as ordered by default; in the latter case - as categorical)
```